# Get SqlConnection failure reason

Tags: c#, enterprise-library, sqlconnection

I have a method that returns whether a connection can be opened.

However, in case of failure I need to notify users whether they've provided bad login credentials or if there's a problem with the database.

Current code:

```
try 
{
    Database db = new SqlDatabase(connectionString);
    using(var connection = db.CreateConnection())
    {
        connection.Open();
        return true;
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    return false;
}
```

Whether it's a problem with credentials or database, the exception is always `SqlException`.

However, I've noticed the following differences:

**Bad credentials**:

- Message: `Login failed for user 'whatever'`
- Class: `14`
- Number: `18456`
- State: `1`

**Bad database**:

- Message: `A network something or other`
- Class: `20`
- Number: `-1`
- State: `0`

...So yes, there are differences, but I'm not sure I can rely on these numbers (and checking the string value of the message makes me feel like I need to take a shower).

According to MSDN, the `Number` property can be a Win32 error code or a server error code, `Class` denotes severity and `State` can give different error codes different meanings.

Is there a better way to determine connection failure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sql Server error codes are [documented](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645934(v=sql.105).aspx) and you can definitely rely on them!

Answer (score 4):

As the [`Class`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception.class(v=vs.110).aspx) property maps to the [Severity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164086.aspx) of the error reported by SQL Server you can use that to determine what action is needed.

From the SQL Server severity table we learn:

- 11-16 Indicate errors that can be corrected by the user.
- 14    Indicates security-related errors, such as permission denied.
- 20    Indicate system problems and are fatal errors...

Your method could return a status code depending if the severity can be fixed by a user or not. Which codes fall in that category is up to your specific requirements but you can imagine something like this:

```csharp
    public enum Status
    {
        Success = 0,
        None,
        RetryUser,
        RetryInfra,
        Network,
        Boom,
        MAX
    }

    public Status ConnectionStatus()
    {
        Status status = Status.None;

        try
        {
            Database db = new SqlDatabase(connectionString);

            using (var connection = db.CreateConnection())
            {
                connection.Open();
                status = Status.Success;
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            switch (ex.Class)
            {
                case 11:
                case 12:
                case 13:
                case 14:
                    status = Status.RetryUser;
                    break;

                case 20:
                    status = Status.RetryInfra;
                    break;

                default:
                    status = Status.Boom;
                    break;
            }
        }

        return status;
    }
```

From [Understanding Database Engine Errors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165761.aspx) at MSDN we learn that `State` is probably not a good candidate to determine the correct next step:

> Some error messages can be raised at multiple points in the code for the Database Engine. For example, an 1105 error can be raised for several different conditions. Each specific condition that raises an error assigns a unique state code.

Comment: Good answer, but this also needs to handle things like network problems.

Comment: @usr I assume an IOException is raised in those cases, right?

Comment: All SqlException. There are some undocumented error code for that.